# Scala, Slick :too many clients already

Tags: scala, connection, client, slick

ive come across this problem :

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

The app works, but i can only make like 3 or 4 requests and then im getting this error, so whats happening (im guessing) is im creating new connections per request and id like to keep one connection per app lifecycle, any idea how to modify the code to do so?

Tried injecting UsersDao to my controller instead of using it as an object but that changes nothing

Im really new to scala so any help is appreciated

Dao

```
import config.DatabaseConfig
import domain.{User, UsersTable}
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import slick.sql.SqlAction

import scala.concurrent.Future
trait BaseDao extends DatabaseConfig {

  val usersTable = TableQuery[UsersTable]


  protected implicit def executeFromDb[A](action: SqlAction[A, NoStream, _ <: slick.dbio.Effect]): Future[A] = {
    println(db)
    db.run(action)
  }

}
object UsersDao extends BaseDao {

  def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = usersTable.result

  def create(user: User): Future[Long] = usersTable.returning(usersTable.map(_.id)) += user

  def findByFirstName(firstName: String): Future[Seq[User]] = usersTable.filter(_.firstName === firstName).result

  def findById(userId: Long): Future[User] = usersTable.filter(_.id === userId).result.head

  def delete(userId: Long): Future[Int] = usersTable.filter(_.id === userId).delete

}
```

DatabaseConfig

```
trait DatabaseConfig extends Config {

  val driver = slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile

  import driver.api._

  def db = Database.forConfig("dbname")
  implicit val session: Session = db.createSession()
}
```

Controller

```
import domain.User
import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._
import repository.UsersDao

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

@Singleton
class UserController @Inject() ()(cc: ControllerComponents, parsers: PlayBodyParsers)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def addUser = Action.async(parse.json[User]) { req => {
    UsersDao.create(req.body).map({ user =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(user))
    })
  }
  }
```

Comment: Since your `def db = Database.forConfig("dbname")` is a `def`. Every `db.createSession()` will create be a new `Database.forConfig("dbname")` call and will result in a new Datebase client which will be used only once to create that `session` and the next createSession will create another client. You need to ensure that you have just one Database object. One way of doing it is to make it `val db = Database.forConfig("dbname")`. And add some mechanism for reconnection only if the current connection breaks,

Comment: Could you please share your `application.conf` for `db` looks like you have not set the maximum connection.